# Extra column names at bottom of data.table

Tags: r, data.table, rbind

I have a problem with a function, the problem is when I run it:

```
selectTrialAnimals <- function(data, nB, nZ, minWeight){
  buitenProef <- data[!is.na(Opm.)]
  tempBiggen <- data[is.na(Opm.)]

  tempBiggen <- tempBiggen[order(Sex,Speen_gew)]

  biggenB <- tempBiggen[Sex=="B"]
  biggenZ <- tempBiggen[Sex=="Z"]

  if (nrow(biggenB[Speen_gew >= minWeight]) >= nB){
    tempBuitenProefB <- biggenB[Speen_gew < minWeight ]
    biggenB <- biggenB[Speen_gew >= minWeight]  
  }else{
    tempBuitenProefB <- biggenB[1: (nrow(biggenB) - nB)]
    biggenB <- biggenB[(nrow(biggenB) - nB + 1):nrow(biggenB)]  
  }

  if (nrow(biggenZ[Speen_gew >= minWeight]) >= nZ){
    tempBuitenProefZ <- biggenZ[Speen_gew < minWeight ]
    biggenZ <- biggenZ[Speen_gew >= minWeight]  
  }else{
    tempBuitenProefZ <- biggenZ[1: (nrow(biggenZ) - nZ)]
    biggenZ <- biggenZ[(nrow(biggenZ) - nZ + 1):nrow(biggenZ)]  
  }

  while (nrow(biggenB) > nB| nrow(biggenZ) > nZ){
    if (nrow(biggenB) > nB){
      if (biggenB[,mean(Speen_gew)] > (biggenZ[,mean(Speen_gew)])){
        tempBuitenProefB <- rbind(tempBuitenProefB,biggenB[nrow(biggenB)])
        biggenB <- biggenB[-nrow(biggenB)]
      }
      if (biggenB[,mean(Speen_gew)] < (biggenZ[,mean(Speen_gew)])){
        tempBuitenProefB <- rbind(tempBuitenProefB,biggenB[1])
        biggenB <- biggenB[-1]      
      }
    }

    if (nrow(biggenZ) > nZ){
      if (biggenZ[,mean(Speen_gew)] > (biggenB[,mean(Speen_gew)])){
        tempBuitenProefZ <- rbind(tempBuitenProefZ,biggenZ[nrow(biggenZ)])
        biggenZ <- biggenZ[-nrow(biggenZ)]
      }
      if (biggenZ[,mean(Speen_gew)] < (biggenB[,mean(Speen_gew)])){
        tempBuitenProefZ <- rbind(tempBuitenProefZ,biggenZ[1])
        biggenZ <- biggenZ[-1]      
      }
    }
  }

  tempBuitenProef <- rbindlist(list(buitenProef,tempBuitenProefB, tempBuitenProefZ))
  tempBuitenProef <- tempBuitenProef[order(Sex,Speen_gew)]
  tempBiggen <- rbind(biggenB, biggenZ)

  return(list(AnimalsInTrial = tempBiggen, AnimalsOutTrial = tempBuitenProef))
}
```

It adds an extra set of column names to the bottom of a data.table it returns. Like so (only part of the result shown):

```
$AnimalsOutTrial
    Sex Oornr    Geb_dat Zeugnr  Beer Geb_gew Speen_gew oud K.H.       Opm.
 1:   B 84001 2020-04-24 18/114 WESLY     0.7       2.2  26   25      breuk
 2:   B 83974 2020-04-23  17/67 WESLY     1.3       3.2  27   24       <NA>
 .....
37:   Z 84081 2020-04-25 18/120 WESLY     0.9       5.3  25   30       <NA>
38:   Z 84085 2020-04-25 18/120 WESLY     1.2       7.0  25   30 dikke poot
    Sex Oornr    Geb_dat Zeugnr  Beer Geb_gew Speen_gew oud K.H.       Opm.
```

Problem is i can't reproduce it with test data:

```
test <- data.table(Sex=c("B","B","Z","Z","B","B","Z","Z"),Opm.=c(NA,"x",NA,NA,"x",NA,NA,NA),Speen_gew=c(1,2,3,5,2,8,7,9))
```

This runs as expected as input. I can't provide the full original data as it is confidential. Has anyone encountered this behavior before and how can I deal with it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The "extra" column names aren't actually there. It's added by the custom `print.data.table` method when the results are printed to the console. Execute `options(datatable.print.colnames = "top")` if you don't like it.

Comment: I believe data.table produces the extra column title at the bottom of the list to make it more readable for you so that you don't have to scroll up to see the column name. It only happens when you have more than certain  number of rows.

Comment: Ah ok, that explains it, thanks!